# Get the latest date for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, greatest-n-per-group

I have a History table (like a log) that records changes to parts:

```
TransactionID    Part ID          Description        Last Updated
1                1                Fixed O-ring       2006-03-14 20:00:04.700
2                2                Replaced coil      2009-01-02 20:00:04.700
3                1                Replaced coil      2009-01-02 20:00:04.700
4                1                Replaced LED       2002-08-20 20:00:04.700      
5                2                Sealed leakage     2007-03-08 20:00:04.700   
6                3                Replace connector  2004-05-16 20:00:04.700
```

I have another table that will show what each Part ID stands for, but that is not the problem I'm facing now. I'm required to write a query that returns the latest maintenance done on every parts. So in this case, my expected output would be:

```
TransactionID    Part ID          Description        Last Updated
2                2                Replaced coil      2009-01-02 20:00:04.700    
3                1                Replaced coil      2009-01-02 20:00:04.700 
6                3                Replace connector  2004-05-16 20:00:04.700
```

Explanation: For example, the latest maintenance for Part ID #1 was completed on 2009-01-02 20:00:04.700 and so on.

I have tried `SELECT DISTINCT` but it won't work because basically every rows will be different. I'm completely out of clue. And if I use `MAX(Last Updated)`, it will only return one row of the entire table.

Edited: In any case, I am NOT allowed to use Dynamic query.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?   Are you familiar with the ROW_NUMBER() function?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, and yes, I have heard of Row_Number(), but not too familiar with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TransactionID
      ,PartID
      ,[Description]
      ,[Last Updated]
FROM (
    SELECT TransactionID
          ,PartID
          ,[Description]
          ,[Last Updated]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PartID] ORDER BY [Last Updated] DESC) RN 
    FROM TableName
    )A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Or you can use CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT TransactionID
          ,PartID
          ,[Description]
          ,[Last Updated]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PartID] ORDER BY [Last Updated] DESC) RN 
    FROM TableName
  )
SELECT TransactionID
      ,PartID
      ,[Description]
      ,[Last Updated]  
FROM CTE 
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Comment: Yea a CTE has its own benefits but for this query it doesnt make much difference, either will do the job.

Comment: I think `RowNumber` over complicates things for this scenario

Comment: What do you suggest then @CSharper ?

Comment: @M.Ali, I'd suggest my response below. I'm not trying to answer snipe so CJ dn't change answers lol but I just think mine is easier to read and less code. Maybe I'm bias though.

Comment: @CSharper I agree your suggestion is simpler than this, and it won't select all the records nor will order it, which will possibly have better performance. Take a look at mine, I think it's even easier :D

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    TransactionID, PartID, Description, LastUpdated
from 
    History H
where
    LastUpdated = 
    (
        select 
            max(LastUpdated) 
        from 
            History
        where
            PartID = H.PartID
    )
```

Comment: Please, let me know if there is some problem with this query.

Comment: Your subquery is not returning a lastupdate for each TransactionID    your subquery is simply returning the max value of lastupdate

Comment: @MelgoV My subquery is returning the last update of each Part ID, which is exactly what was asked by OP.

Comment: @MelgoV Please, read the question and answer carefully before downvote it.

Comment: @MelgoV You can undo your downvote or you can ask me if you haven't yet understood how this SQL technique works.

Comment: Please ask to @C.J. if your query is returning what he was expecting.

Comment: @MelgoV I know it is. I've used this technique many times. You should try it yourself. It's always good to learn new things.

Comment: you are right, so sorry, next time I will be carefully, Thanks for teach me, in this moment i can´t vote up, but I will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61304/discussion-between-melgov-and-caffe).

Comment: @Caffé I like it! No need for the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's How I would do it

```
 ;WITH CTE AS 
 (
 Select PartId, MAX(LASTUPDATED) as 'MAXX' from part group by PartId
 ) 
 Select TransActionId, p.PartId, Description, p.LASTUPDATED
 from Part p
 inner join CTE on p.LastUpdated = CTE.MAXX
                and p.PartId = CTE.PartId
```

Comment: But then if there are any ties for MAX(LASTUPDATED) wouldn't you get an undesired Cartesian join?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.TransactionID, t.PartID, t.Description, t.LastUpdated
FROM History t
JOIN (SELECT PartID, MAX(TransactionID)
FROM History
GROUP BY PartID) t2 ON t.PartID = t2.PartID
AND t.TransactionID = t2.TransactionID
```

will also work.

Comment: Do you mean MAX(Last Updated)?

Comment: Well, I debated about that :)  I made an assumption that the TransactionID was unique and incremental (that may not be the case); I always worry that dates are not unique, and so may throw off results.