# TSQL Distinct Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that is selecting employees from a table.

The table is a historical table so it can contain records for the same person. The one piece of data that is always the same is `A.[qid]`. The employees name could change so it would insert another record with the changes.

I am trying to select the most recent record for the employee which is why i am ordering by `A.[Meta_LogDate]`. However, I only want to include 1 record for the employee, not all of them.

When I search, I expect it to give me the most recent record in this table.

I dont think I can do `Top` because this is an ajax call that is narrowing down the employees as you type so I need to make sure the list still shows all the possible options, just not duplicates.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(A.[qid]),
         A.[FirstName],
         A.[LastName],
         A.[ntid],
         A.[Meta_LogDate]
FROM     EmpTable_historical AS A
WHERE    A.[LastName] + ', ' + A.[FirstName] LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
ORDER BY A.[LastName], A.[Meta_LogDate] DESC
FOR      XML PATH ('emp'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('results');
```

Comment: I think your question is similar to mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855021/get-the-latest-date-for-each-record/25855098?noredirect=1#comment40458470_25855098

Comment: If you are using this for an autocomplete field, you will take a big performance hit by querying a historical database with filtering and sorting on every keystroke. It would be better to have a "Live" or "Current" table, and probably a FREETEXT index to provide more efficient text matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY qid ORDER BY Meta_LogDate DESC)
    FROM EmpTable_historical 
    WHERE [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName] LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```