# Select a distinct ID with the maximum date

Tags: sql, db2

I see some questions relating to mine, but they are not exactly the same.

I need to make a SELECT in a DB2 database where I keep only distinct IDs with their data.

Example, I have some datas :

```
ID    DATE_BEGIN   DATE_END
1111  2014-01-01   2016-01-02
1111  2018-01-05   2018-01-03
1111  1990-01-01   9999-12-31
2222  1998-02-02   2000-12-20
```

In my case, I want to keep :

```
1111  1990-01-01   9999-12-31
2222  1998-02-02   2000-12-20
```

My SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
ID, DATE_BEGIN, DATE_END
FROM TABLE_NAME T1
WHERE DATE_END = (SELECT
                  MAX(DATE_END)
                  FROM TABLE_NAME T2
                  WHERE T2.DATE_END = T1.DATE_END)
```

But I keep getting every records.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The answer by C.J is the best solution, but your query will also work if you change `WHERE T2.DATE_END = T1.DATE_END` to `WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID`

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I wonder what would happen with more than one date at 9999-12-31.

Comment: In that case you will have a draw, i.e. both rows will satisfy the condition. If you change row_number() to rank() in C.J.'s answer you will get the same effect there. If you want to emulate row_number() in case of a draw you could do: `select id, min(date_begin), date_end ... group by id, date_end`

Comment: This is a [bog-standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value) [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question previously, please refer to my post here: [Get the latest date for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855021/get-the-latest-date-for-each-record)

```
SELECT ID, DATE_BEGIN, DATE_END
FROM (
SELECT ID, DATE_BEGIN, DATE_END
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DATE_END] DESC) RN 
FROM TABLE_NAME
)A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Credit goes to the original answer in my post.

Comment: Wow ! It works just fine ! I didn't even know it existed. Thanks a lot et thanks too to the original poster. Now I'm feeling cheep because I can't even give a rep point to both of you because I don't have 15 rep points... But THANKS A LOT !